# Error while compiling OpenTLD compile.m

Tags: c++, matlab, visual-studio, opencv, mex

I am trying to compile the mex files needed to run OpenTLD project.

Link : https://github.com/zk00006/OpenTLD

Using:

OpenCV 2.4.9 64-bit, 
Matlab 2013b 64-bit

When trying to run compile.m, I get the following error.

```
Creating library C:\Users\Saurabh\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_sT0LV8\templib.x and object C:\Users\Saurabh\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_sT0LV8\templib.exp 
lk.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol cvAlloc referenced in function mexFunction 
lk.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol cvCreateImage referenced in function "void __cdecl normCrossCorrelation(struct _IplImage *,struct _IplImage *,struct CvPoint2D32f *,struct CvPoint2D32f *,int,char *,float *,int,int)" (?normCrossCorrelation@@YAXPEAU_IplImage@@0PEAUCvPoint2D32f@@1HPEADPEAMHH@Z) 
lk.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol cvReleaseImage referenced in function "void __cdecl normCrossCorrelation(struct _IplImage *,struct _IplImage *,struct CvPoint2D32f *,struct CvPoint2D32f *,int,char *,float *,int,int)" (?normCrossCorrelation@@YAXPEAU_IplImage@@0PEAUCvPoint2D32f@@1HPEADPEAMHH@Z) 
lk.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol cvGetRectSubPix referenced in function "void __cdecl normCrossCorrelation(struct _IplImage *,struct _IplImage *,struct CvPoint2D32f *,struct CvPoint2D32f *,int,char *,float *,int,int)" (?normCrossCorrelation@@YAXPEAU_IplImage@@0PEAUCvPoint2D32f@@1HPEADPEAMHH@Z) 
lk.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol cvMatchTemplate referenced in function "void __cdecl normCrossCorrelation(struct _IplImage *,struct _IplImage *,struct CvPoint2D32f *,struct CvPoint2D32f *,int,char *,float *,int,int)" (?normCrossCorrelation@@YAXPEAU_IplImage@@0PEAUCvPoint2D32f@@1HPEADPEAMHH@Z) 
lk.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol cvCalcOpticalFlowPyrLK referenced in function mexFunction 
lk.mexw64 : fatal error LNK1120: 6 unresolved externals 

  C:\PROGRA~1\MATLAB\R2013B\BIN\MEX.PL: Error: Link of 'lk.mexw64' failed. 

Unable to complete successfully.

Error in compile (line 32)
    eval(['mex lk.cpp -O' include lib]);
```

I know it has something to do with using wrong bit version(32/64) of one of the OpenCV or Matlab to build, but still can't resolve the issue.

Comment: That distribution of OpenTLD appears to be an **ancient** fork of the canonical repository.  Try getting OpenTLD from [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/gnebehay/OpenTLD) instead, which is maintained by [the authors](http://www.gnebehay.com/tld/).  Or this: http://www.gnebehay.com/cmt/

Comment: Did you make sure to update your `compile.m` so that you're pointing to the directory of where your OpenCV libraries are located?  Make sure you change the `include` and `libpath` variables so that they're pointing to where they need to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue, it was some syntax issue as I was using a recent version of Matlab, 2013b. It's funny how all the forums online pointed me towards the 32-64 bit problem. Anyway I am posting the solution here so that in future it might help someone.

This was the modification I made in compile.m. Lines 25-30:

```
files = dir(fullfile(libpath, '*.lib'));

lib = [];
for i = 1:length(files),
   lib = [lib ' ' libpath '\' files(i).name];
end
```

It was not reading the .lib files in the variable lib properly before and thus error in linking.